# Am I missing badges I should have earned?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I believe I am missing 2-3 badges.

For my current reputation of 115 the breakdown looks like this:

- 1 initial reputation point.
- 2 post edits.
- 112 tag wiki edits.

The lone edit was adding a tag to a question, which should qualify me for one or both of *Organizer* and *Editor*. The other missing badge is *Research Assistant* for 56 tag wiki edits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Edits to Excerpts do not qualify you for the Research Assistant Badge.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119550/new-silver-badge-for-editing-n-tag-wikis/121484#121484)

[Retagging a question does not qualify you for the Editor badge.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/445/135415)

It looks like you may qualify for the Organizer badge though, maybe. The actual 'retagging' ability isn't actually available to you until 500 rep, but now that anyone can put in a suggested edit that doesn't matter as much.

Possibly, it has something to do with the question having been migrated, and still missing a proper user account?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.